# Bash ERR signal not trapped in procedures?

Tags: bash, signals

Consider the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "ERROR" && exit 2' ERR

proc(){
   false
   return 0
}
echo START

proc

echo END
```

The above shows output

```
START
END
```

but I would expect the **false** command to trigger the trap procedure for the ERR signal.

If I put **false** instead of the call to **proc** the signal is triggered and output

```
START
ERROR
```

is shown as expected. If I put the **trap** command again at the beginning of **proc** procedure, it is again being correctly trapped.

How is it so that trapping only works outside of procedures, unless **trap** command is repeated in the procedure? I could not find any documentation on that.

I got the same behavior on bash versions 3.1.0, 3.2.25, 4.1.17 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting `man bash` on FUNCTIONS:

> the ERR trap is
>          not inherited unless the `-o errtrace` shell option has been enabled.

So, just add

```
set -o errtrace
```

to the script and it starts working.